# Missing accessibility label: in Android Studio Warning

Tags: android, android-studio

> Missing accessibility label:  where `minSdk < 17`,  you should provide
>   an `android:hint` Editable text fields should provide an `android:hint`
>   or, provided your minSdkVersion is at least 17, they may be referenced
>   by a view with a `android:labelFor` attribute.  When using
>   `android:labelFor`, be sure to provide an `android:text` or an 
>   `android:contentDescription`.  If your view is labeled but by a label in
>   a different layout which includes this one, just suppress this warning
>   from lint.
>
> Issue id: LabelFor

How can fix this warning?

Comment: Which widget warned you about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add

```
tools:ignore="LabelFor"
```

in your xml.

Comment: The warning may go away, but the problem doesn't and visually impaired people using TalkBack will have trouble using manjitha's fancy app. It's better to just add meaningful `android:hint` or `android:labelFor` and feel good about oneself. :)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Does it occur only for `EditText`s?

Comment: I got this error for button.  the issue is resolved by add abv line but   can you just explain the reason behind the error ?

Answer (score 2):

**I had I same problem. I fix it like this**

Use @String/example for name your method
   Follow these steps

- Go to **Res>Values>Stings.xml**add a string like this

  ```
   Enter Number 1
  ```

  - and go to your Text or button Attributes and replace text use String

  @String/Enter_Number_1

  if required asking of hind just add this code with your hint

  android:autofillHints=""

Comment: <string name="Enter_Number_1">Enter Number 1</string>

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of widget you get this error on, you can choose a suitable label for it so that it will be "more" accessible.

For example, I have an `AutoCompleteTextView`, which has no Hint/text, etc. so it is not easy for everyone to notice it, therefore I add a hint like `"enter your text here"` which works as  `"HEY I AM HERE, COME Use me!"`

You can add a text like
`android:text="@string/default_lat"`,

hint like
`android:hint="@string/SomeHint"`

or label like
`android:labelFor="SomeLabel"`

For more information click [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add **lint.xml** file in the **src** (source) folder of your project:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<lint>
    <issue id="ContentDescription" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

Or inside of **ImageView** or xml element you can also add:

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android wants you to help user.** Just set a hint :

for example:

```
 android:hint="@string/my_edittext"
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide an android:hint  Editable text fields should provide an 
android:hint or, provided your minSdkVersion is at least 17, they may be referenced by a view with a android:labelFor attribute. 
When using android:labelFor, be sure to provide an android:text or an android:contentDescription. 
If your view is labeled but by a label in a different layout which includes this one, just suppress this warning from lint.

Answer (score 0):

Add some hint to the "hint" in attributes of the "Text object"(e.g. "Plain Text").

or you don't want to add hint.
Just add:

```
tools:ignore="LabelFor"
```

in xml(activity_main.xml) code to ignore the warning.